# Adding onclick attribute in jQuery issue

Tags: jquery

I have a carousel with a next and prev button. They have a class name `nav-arrow`. My problem is the there are not button. They are `<a>`. Having the `href` value `#`. So when i clicked on them the scroll jump to the top.
So  I made this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function(){  
        var js = "return false;";
        var newclick = new Function(js);
        jQuery(".nav-arrow").each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr('onclick', '').click(newclick);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

and it works.
BUT If i changed my script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function(){  
        var js = "return false;";
        //var newclick = new Function(js);
        jQuery(".nav-arrow").each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr('onclick', js);
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

it doesn't. WHY ?? I don't get it..

Comment: You dont get why attaching a function to an onclick handler works, but just adding text ("return false") doesn't? Really?

Comment: @Jamiec Actually, they both are working. Setting the attribute `onclick="return false"` is expected to work and it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `onclick` attributes is not a good practice. Adding handlers to your elements is much better in this case:

```
jQuery(".nav-arrow").on("click", function () {
    return false;
});
```

---

Your second example also works. See below. Make sure the elements exist on the page.

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  var js = "return false;";
  //var newclick = new Function(js);
  jQuery(".nav-arrow").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('onclick', js);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com" class="nav-arrow">test</a>
```

Note that if the page is loaded, `load` will not be fired again. You may use `ready` instead:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
  var js = "return false;";
  //var newclick = new Function(js);
  jQuery(".nav-arrow").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('onclick', js);
  });
});
```

Comment: ok I understand that. But it was not my question . My question is why my first method works and the other one NOT  .Thx :)

Comment: @Chester See my edit. Improved the things a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

In second case you are just attaching a string value to `onclick` handler. Hence its not working. It expect a function and it found a string. So it doesn't do anything. But if you do something like your first approach or the below one then it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function(){  
        var js = "return false;";

        jQuery(".nav-arrow").each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr('onclick', function(){
               eval(js); //evaluating the string into javascript code
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware, returning `false` from jQuery event handler is shorthand for `event.preventDefault();` **&** `event.stopPropagation();`. While returning `false` from inline js script only prevent default behaviour, not stopping propagation.

So i guess your issue (if any?!), if you see different behaviour, is because in your second case click event bubbles to parent(s).